Image not loading after exiting the conversation
When I send an image in my conversation, the receiver receives the url of the image, whilst the sender can see it, but after exiting the conversation, the sender only sees the url. I am using firebase as my database with a storage path named "chat_images/"
ChatActivity.java
package com.example.sparks.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.example.sparks.adapters.ChatAdapter;
import com.example.sparks.databinding.ActivityChatBinding;
import com.example.sparks.models.ChatMessage;
import com.example.sparks.models.User;
import com.example.sparks.network.ApiClient;
import com.example.sparks.network.ApiService;
import com.example.sparks.utilities.Constants;
import com.example.sparks.utilities.PreferenceManager;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.firebase.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class ChatActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private ActivityChatBinding binding;
    private User receiverUser;
    private List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
    private List<String> imageMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
    private PreferenceManager preferenceManager;
    private FirebaseFirestore database;
    private String conversionId = null;
    private Boolean isReceiverAvailable = false;
    private Uri selectedImageUri; // Add this line to store the selected image URI

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        setListeners();
        loadReceiverDetails();
        init();
        listenMessages();
    }

    private void init(){
        preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
        chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(
                chatMessages,
                getBitmapFromEncodedString(receiverUser.image),
                preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID),
                imageMessages
        );
        binding.chatRecyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    private void sendMessage(String imageUrl) {
        HashMap<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>();
        message.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
        message.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, receiverUser.id);

        if (imageUrl != null) {
            message.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE, imageUrl);
            imageMessages.add(imageUrl);
        } else {
            message.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
        }

        message.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP, new Date());
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT).add(message);

        if (conversionId != null) {
            updateConversion(binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
        } else {
            HashMap<String, Object> conversion = new HashMap<>();
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_IMAGE, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, receiverUser.id);
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_NAME, receiverUser.name);
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_IMAGE, receiverUser.image);
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP, new Date());
            addConversion(conversion);
        }

        if (!isReceiverAvailable) {
            try {
                JSONArray tokens = new JSONArray();
                tokens.put(receiverUser.token);

                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                data.put(Constants.KEY_USER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_NAME, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());

                JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
                body.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_DATA, data);
                body.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_REGISTRATION_IDS, tokens);

                sendNotification(body.toString());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                showToast(exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
        binding.inputMessage.setText(null);
        selectedImageUri = null;
    }

    private void uploadImageAndSendMessage(Uri imageUri) {
        // Generate a unique filename for the image using UUID
        String imageFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        // Get a reference to the Firebase Storage location with the unique filename
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("chat_images/" + imageFileName);

        // Upload the image to Firebase Storage with the unique filename
        storageReference.putFile(imageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    // Once the upload is successful, get the download URL
                    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                        // Send message with the download URL of the image
                        sendMessage(uri.toString());
                    });
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> showToast(e.getMessage()));
    }

    private void showToast(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody){
        ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class).sendMessage(
                Constants.getRemoteMsgHeaders(),
                messageBody
        ).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    try {
                        if (response.body() != null){
                            JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response.body());
                            JSONArray results = responseJson.getJSONArray("resuults");
                            if (responseJson.getInt("failure") == 1){
                                JSONObject error = (JSONObject) results.get(0);
                                showToast(error.getString("error"));
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    showToast("Notification sent successfully");
                }else {
                    showToast("Error: " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                showToast(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void listenAvailabilityOfReceiver(){
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS).document(
                receiverUser.id
        ).addSnapshotListener(ChatActivity.this, (value, error) -> {
            if (error != null){
                return;
            }
            if (value != null){
                if (value.getLong(Constants.KEY_AVAILABILITY) != null) {
                    int availability = Objects.requireNonNull(
                            value.getLong(Constants.KEY_AVAILABILITY)
                    ).intValue();
                    isReceiverAvailable = availability == 1;
                }
                receiverUser.token = value.getString(Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN);
                if (receiverUser.image == null){
                    receiverUser.image = value.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE);
                    chatAdapter.setReceiverProfileImage(getBitmapFromEncodedString(receiverUser.image));
                    chatAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, chatMessages.size());
                }
            }
            if (isReceiverAvailable){
                binding.textAvailability.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                binding.textAvailability.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void listenMessages(){
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID))
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, receiverUser.id)
                .addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, receiverUser.id)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID))
                .addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
    }

    private final EventListener<QuerySnapshot> eventListener = (value, error) -> {
        if (error != null) {
            return;
        }
        if (value != null) {
            int count = chatMessages.size();
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
                    chatMessage.senderId = documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID);
                    chatMessage.receiverId = documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID);
                    chatMessage.message = documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE);
                    chatMessage.dateTime = getReadableDateTime(documentChange.getDocument().getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP));
                    chatMessage.dateObject = documentChange.getDocument().getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP);
                    chatMessages.add(chatMessage);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(chatMessages, (obj1, obj2) -> obj1.dateObject.compareTo(obj2.dateObject));
            if (count == 0) {
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                chatAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(chatMessages.size(), chatMessages.size());
                binding.chatRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(chatMessages.size() - 1);
            }
            binding.chatRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (conversionId == null) {
            checkForConversion();
        }
    };

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromEncodedString(String encodedImage){
        if (encodedImage != null){
            byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void loadReceiverDetails(){
        receiverUser = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Constants.KEY_USER);
        binding.textName.setText(receiverUser.name);
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        binding.imageBack.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
        binding.layoutSend.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (selectedImageUri != null) {
                uploadImageAndSendMessage(selectedImageUri);
            } else {
                sendMessage(null);
            }
        });
        binding.mediaAttach.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        }
    }


    private String getReadableDateTime(Date date){
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
    }

    private void addConversion(HashMap<String, Object> conversion){
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATIONS)
                .add(conversion)
                .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> conversionId = documentReference.getId());
    }

    private void updateConversion(String message){
        DocumentReference documentReference =
                database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATIONS).document(conversionId);
        documentReference.update(
                Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE, message,
                Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP, new Date()
        );
    }

    private void checkForConversion(){
        if(!chatMessages.isEmpty()){
            checkForConversionRemotely(
                    preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID),
                    receiverUser.id
            );
            checkForConversionRemotely(
                    receiverUser.id,
                    preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID)
            );
        }
    }

    private void checkForConversionRemotely(String senderId, String receiverid){
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATIONS)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, senderId)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, receiverid)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(conversionOnCompleteListener);
    }

    private final OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> conversionOnCompleteListener = task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null && !task.getResult().getDocuments().isEmpty()){
            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0);
            conversionId = documentSnapshot.getId();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        listenAvailabilityOfReceiver();
    }
}

ChatAdapter.java
package com.example.sparks.adapters;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.sparks.databinding.ItemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding;
import com.example.sparks.databinding.ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding;
import com.example.sparks.databinding.ItemContainerSentMediaMessageBinding;
import com.example.sparks.databinding.ItemContainerSentMessageBinding;
import com.example.sparks.models.ChatMessage;

import java.util.List;

public class ChatAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;

    private Bitmap receiverProfileImage;
    private final String senderId;

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SENT = 1;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED = 2;

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SENT_IMAGE = 3;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED_IMAGE = 4;
    private List<String> imageMessages;

    public void setReceiverProfileImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        receiverProfileImage = bitmap;
    }

    public ChatAdapter(List<ChatMessage> chatMessages, Bitmap receiverProfileImage, String senderId, List<String> imageMessages) {
        this.chatMessages = chatMessages;
        this.receiverProfileImage = receiverProfileImage;
        this.senderId = senderId;
        this.imageMessages = imageMessages;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_SENT) {
            return new SentMessageViewHolder(
                    ItemContainerSentMessageBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                            parent,
                            false
                    )
            );
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED) {
            return new ReceivedMessageViewHolder(
                    ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                            parent,
                            false
                    ),
                    ItemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                            parent,
                            false
                    )
            );
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_SENT_IMAGE) {
            return new SentImageMessageViewHolder(
                    ItemContainerSentMediaMessageBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                            parent,
                            false
                    )
            );
        } else {
            return new ReceivedImageMessageViewHolder(
                    ItemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                            parent,
                            false
                    )
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        ChatMessage message = chatMessages.get(position);
        boolean isSender = message.senderId.equals(senderId);
        boolean isImageMessage = imageMessages.contains(message.message);

        if (isSender) {
            return isImageMessage ? VIEW_TYPE_SENT_IMAGE : VIEW_TYPE_SENT;
        } else {
            return isImageMessage ? VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED_IMAGE : VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ChatMessage message = chatMessages.get(position);

        if (holder instanceof SentMessageViewHolder) {
            ((SentMessageViewHolder) holder).setData(message);
        } else if (holder instanceof ReceivedMessageViewHolder) {
            ((ReceivedMessageViewHolder) holder).setData(message, receiverProfileImage);
        } else if (holder instanceof SentImageMessageViewHolder) {
            ((SentImageMessageViewHolder) holder).setData(message);
        } else if (holder instanceof ReceivedImageMessageViewHolder) {
            ((ReceivedImageMessageViewHolder) holder).setData(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatMessages.size();
    }


    static class SentMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ItemContainerSentMessageBinding binding;

        SentMessageViewHolder(ItemContainerSentMessageBinding itemContainerSentMessageBinding) {
            super(itemContainerSentMessageBinding.getRoot());
            binding = itemContainerSentMessageBinding;
        }

        void setData(ChatMessage chatMessage) {
            binding.textMessage.setText(chatMessage.message);
            binding.textDateTime.setText(chatMessage.dateTime);
        }
    }

    static class ReceivedMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding binding;
        private final ItemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding mediaBinding;

        ReceivedMessageViewHolder(ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding itemContainerReceivedMessageBinding, ItemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding itemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding) {
            super(itemContainerReceivedMessageBinding.getRoot());
            binding = itemContainerReceivedMessageBinding;
            mediaBinding = itemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding;
        }

        void setData(ChatMessage chatMessage, Bitmap receiverProfileImage) {
            if (isImageUrl(chatMessage.message)) {
                binding.getRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mediaBinding.getRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Glide.with(mediaBinding.getRoot().getContext())
                        .load(chatMessage.message)
                        .into(mediaBinding.imageMessage);
                mediaBinding.textDateTime.setText(chatMessage.dateTime);
                if (receiverProfileImage != null) {
                    mediaBinding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(receiverProfileImage);
                }
            } else {
                binding.getRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mediaBinding.getRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                binding.textMessage.setText(chatMessage.message);
                binding.textDateTime.setText(chatMessage.dateTime);
                if (receiverProfileImage != null) {
                    binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(receiverProfileImage);
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isImageUrl(String url) {
            return url != null && (url.endsWith(".jpg") || url.endsWith(".jpeg") || url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".gif"));
        }
    }


    static class SentImageMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final ItemContainerSentMediaMessageBinding binding;

        SentImageMessageViewHolder(ItemContainerSentMediaMessageBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        void setData(ChatMessage chatMessage) {
            Glide.with(binding.getRoot().getContext())
                    .load(chatMessage.message)
                    .into(binding.imageMessage);
        }
    }

    static class ReceivedImageMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final ItemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding binding;

        ReceivedImageMessageViewHolder(ItemContainerReceivedMediaMessageBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        void setData(ChatMessage chatMessage) {
            Glide.with(binding.getRoot().getContext())
                    .load(chatMessage.message)
                    .into(binding.imageMessage);
        }
    }
}


These are somewhat lengthy classes. Is it possible to make a smaller reproducible test-case and to include that in your question instead?
